# Class instance with names defined by string

Tags: ruby

In 'pure ruby' (not rails), given a class:

```
class Person
end
```

...and an array of strings:

```
people_names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Barbara', 'Bob']
```

how can I instantiate the `Person` class, with each instance variable named one of the elements in my array?

```
John = Person.new
Jane = Person.new
Barbara = Person.new
Bob = Person.new
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that using capital letters for variable names makes them constants. Not sure if that's what you're aiming for here

Comment: That dup target was about local variables. This question is actually about constants - its just really poorly worded.

Comment: I don't see any indication this question is about constants other than the sample code, it's never made clear them being constants is intended and I'm assuming the author may not be aware that in Ruby a variable is constant if the first letter is capital.

Comment: He's also asking about instance variables but there is no @ sigil. Actually I don't know what to make of it. @BrandonBuck

Comment: Yea that's my point, there really isn't enough information to reach a determination exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty unclear what you actually want here since an identifier in ruby starting with an uppercase letter in Ruby is a constant.

```
John = Person.new
Jane = Person.new
Barbara = Person.new
Bob = Person.new
```

You can dynamically assign constants with [`Module#const_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Module.html#method-i-const_set).

```
module MyModule
  ['John', 'Jane', 'Barbara', 'Bob'].each do |name|
    const_set(name, Person.new)
  end
end

# this imports the constants into Main which is the global scope
include MyModule

John
=> #<Person:0x007f973586a618>
```

Instance variables on the other hand use the @ sigil. You can dynamically assign instance variables with [instance_variable_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get):

```
['John', 'Jane', 'Barbara', 'Bob'].map(&:downcase).each do |name|
  instance_variable_set("@#{name}", Person.new)
end

@john       
# => #<Person:0x007f9734089530>
```

While you can declare an instance variable named @John it violates the conventions of the language.

Local variables cannot actually be defined dynamically. You can only change existing variables via [`eval`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) and [`binding.local_variable_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set).

```
def foo
  a = 1
  bind = binding
  bind.local_variable_set(:a, 2) # set existing local variable `a'
  bind.local_variable_set(:b, 3) # create new local variable `b'
                                 # `b' exists only in binding

  p bind.local_variable_get(:a)  #=> 2
  p bind.local_variable_get(:b)  #=> 3
  p a                            #=> 2
  p b                            #=> NameError
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure Ruby has some means for you into defining constants dynamically, but I'm not going to bother looking that up because this feels, almost 100%, like something you don't really want to do. It seems like you want some way to associate a "name" to a class instance. That is exactly what `Hash` is for.

```
people_names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Barbara', 'Bob']
people = people_names.each_with_object({}) do |name, ppl|
  ppl[name] = Person.new(name)
end
people['John'].name # => 'John'
people['Jane'].name # => 'Jane'
```

Why do I say what you're asking for is probably not what you want? Because use meta programming to dynamically create and dynamically read from local variables/constants/instance variables is just generally frowned upon in professional development. For your own projects, for experimentation, sure maybe. For any project as part of a team though, when you start using meta-programming features to dynamically add these values and reference them (maybe directly, maybe indirectly later) is all well and good but when you try and figure out what's going on you will almost never be able to figure out where these things are defined/coming from unless the array with the dynamic names is hard coded. And if it's hard-coded why can't you just build the constants/variables/targets directly in the code? That's significantly better than dynamically doing it.

```
# this is a fake API to demonstrate
# let's assume this is what you want
PEOPLE_NAMES = ['John', 'Jane']
PEOPLE_NAMES.each do |name|
  const_def(name, Person.new)
end

get_person('Jane').do_something # maps to const_get('Jane').do_something
get_person(PEOPLE_NAMES[0]).do_something
John.do_something
```

If you want the above, why can't you just do:

```
John = Person.new
Jane = Person.new

John.do_something
```

The latter is loads more clear, can still be dynamically looked up, but has a hardcoded definition that can easily be targeted when debugging.

That's my recommendation and answer. I'm pretty sure you don't want to do what you're asking to do. `Hash` totally fits the needs you desire, it's used heavily for purposes like this and closely related to it, I recommend you try and make that work for your needs then try and figure how to solve the problem you're specifically looking to get an answer too.

**EDIT**

As a really fun add-on, you can do some really cool dynamic stuff with `Hash` here that doesn't lead to tons of confusion unless you happen to hide where the hash is coming from. But you could do something like:

```
people = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Person.new(k) }
# right now, people contains no actual people
people['John'].name # => 'John'
# now people contains one Person instance
```

This is cool for two reasons 1) You don't have to have a list to generate the hash, so if you get names after hash creation that's fine you can just add them by accessing that users name and 2) Being lazy, it will only use the memory you need. If you preload the hash with all four persons, and then access data from only two persons you wasted the space required for the unused 2 `Person` instances, so this let's you use only as much as you need and otherwise offers you all the same benefits.

Comment: As an addon, the hash variable you use can be a constant/instance variable/local variable, basically assigned to any kind of variable you want. It can be passed to functions, copied, etc... it's way more versatile than some scope-local means of defining dynamic data.

Comment: Uh, Rails uses tons of dynamic instance/constant assignment. But I guess thats frowned upon by so called professional developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do it, although as Brandon says it probably isn't a good idea. Here's how to do it:

```
people_names.each { |name| eval("#{name} = Person.new")}
```

`eval` takes a string passed as an argument and executes it as a line of code. So, you use `each` to do that once for each member of your array.

You might want to google "eval" to see any number of articles about why it's evil. Many of these go off on metaprogramming (`eval` is an example of metaprogramming) in general, and make some good points. I have a bit more moderate approach to metaprogramming than that (`attr_accessor`, after all, is an example of metaprogramming, too, and people use it all the time), but you can certainly write some very tangled code using `eval`.

Note also, as several posters have observed, that by capitalizing your strings you are defining them as constants. You can change a constant's value in Ruby, but you will get a warning every time you do so.

Comment: eval will not actually define new local variables. `eval('John = Person.new'); John` works. But `eval('john = Person.new'); john` with give a NameError.

Comment: @max So it does. Bad idea all around then. :) Actually, it will define new local variables, though: `eval("a = 7")` works too. Seems that perhaps it just won't let you define class instances?

Comment: Nope, i'm pretty sure it does not declare new instance variables. I'm guessing you already declared `a`. This is explained in the docs for [binding.local_variable_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set) which works exactly like eval in this regard.

Comment: I personally find it erroneous the language allows the reassignment of a constant. What's the point of a "constant" if it's not, you know, _constant_? I can get behind using something like `const_set` that allowed the reassignment of a constant (with the warning), but I think a native hardcoded reassignment should have been an Error.

Comment: This is using the Death Star to swat a fly. What's wrong with `const_set`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag That would be a better solution. I don't think the OP wants to use constants really, though. Probably didn't realize that capitalizing the names resulted in them being constants. So, probably not a good idea all around.

Comment: @max You're right! That's what I did. I've been learning a bit more about `eval`. From Matz's book: "Note that `eval` evaluates its code in a temporary scope. `eval` can alter the value of instance variables that already exist. But any new instance variables it defines are local to the invocation of eval and cease to exist when it returns. (It is as if the evaluated code is run in the body of a block — variables local to a block do not exist outside the block.)" So, not a good solution.